# android selector

Tags: java, android, selector

I use a Gallery to display Contacts's info,on the item view,there has two button which i use selector as their background,now here is the problem,i touch the area out of this two button,this two button will change the background seem like they are all pressed.
here is the gallery item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="#505050"
  >
  <ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/phone_contact_image"
    android:layout_height="160dip"
    android:layout_width="160dip"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dip"
    android:src="@drawable/contact_phone_image_1"
    />
  <TextView  
    android:id="@+id/phone_contact_name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    android:textSize="25dip"
    android:layout_below="@id/phone_contact_image"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    />
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/phone_contact_numbler"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textSize="25dip"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@id/phone_contact_name"
    android:text="@string/contact_phone_numbler"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    />
  <Button 
    android:id="@+id/phone_contact_edit_btn"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:text="@string/editContact_title_edit"
    android:textSize="28dip"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_button_bg"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_below="@id/phone_contact_numbler"
    />
  <Button 
    android:id="@+id/phone_contact_call_btn"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:text="@string/title_call_via"
    android:textSize="28dip"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_confirm_bg"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dip"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_below="@id/phone_contact_edit_btn"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

here is the selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_button_focus" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_button_pressed" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_button_normal" />
</selector>
```

Comment: have you tried below suggested solution?

Comment: hi,i find some new clues,i use no background.but..you may look this (https://www.dropbox.com/s/5cbwvchl8hrfz1e/2012-09-11%2009.52.53.mp4 )

Comment: the final solution is new a class extends from Button,and override a method:    @Override
    public void setPressed(boolean pressed) {
        // If the parent is pressed, do not set to pressed.
        if (pressed && ((View) getParent()).isPressed()) {
            return;
        }
        super.setPressed(pressed);
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are right. But you didnt mentioned when the state is not pressed or not focused and not selected then what you will do?

Try this:
**make a styles.xml file in you res.values folder**
and add it.

```
 <style name="styleNormalButton">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/backgroundbutton</item>
    </style>
```

consider the *`@drawable/backgroundbutton.xml`* is your selector file and add the below code in that.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_button_focus" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_button_pressed"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_pressed_holo_dark"
      android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_button_normal" />
</selector>
```

and finally into your layou file.
set the background of the button to *`style/styleNormalButton`*

hope this will help you

Comment: I tried just now, It seems doesn't work. I consider that state_enabled is prepare for disable,so i ignore it...did i miss something eles?

Comment: see if still not wotking then, go by bottom up approach. i mean set the state focused and pressed to false and give the default background there. try this and let me know

Comment: did you mean like this?not working...
 <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_button_normal" />
 <item android:state_focused="false" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_button_normal" />
 <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_button_normal" />

Comment: I record a vedio for this bug(https://www.dropbox.com/s/k00fov63w1jcdnr/2012-09-10%2016.28.43.mp4 ),you will see i'm definitely an incompetent cameraman

Comment: set style/styleNormalButton background to both the buttons.

Comment: i got a crash----Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path),,,,i confuse that if background could use style res

Comment: I tried use  com.android.contacts.ui.widget.DontPressWithParentImageView instead of Button,It seems worded,but i need find a way to add some text on it..anyway, tks for help